# Presenter sometimes returns null

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I use Dagger 2 on my application to DI and MVP. I inject the component on the onCreate method, like this (it`s on Fragment):

```
private MyComponent myComponent;

@Inject MyPresenter myPresenter;

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  myComponent().inject(this);
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public MyComponent myComponent() {
  if(myComponent == null) {
    myComponent = DaggerMyComponent.builder()
      .applicationComponent(((MyAppApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext()).component())
      .myModule(new MyModule())
      .build();
  }
  return myComponent;
}
```

Sometimes I call a method (from Activity, the lifecycle of both are ended, the user can call this method anytime[Swipe to refresh]) that uses myPresenter, like this:

```
public void doSomething() {
  if(myPresenter != null) {
    myPresenter.doSomething();
  } else {
    //FAIL HERE!
  }
}
```

Component:

```
@ActivityScope @Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class,
    modules = { MyModule.class })
public interface MyComponent {
  void inject(MyFragment myFragment);
  MyPresenter getMyPresenter();
  GetMyExecutor getExecutor();
}
```

Module:

```
@Module public class MyModule {

  @Provides @ActivityScope MyPresenter provideMyPresenter(MyPresenterImpl presenter) {
    return presenter;
  }

  @Provides @ActivityScope GetMyExecutor provideGetMyExecutor(
  GetMyExecutorImpl getMyExecutor) {
    return getMyExecutor;
  }

}
```

I`m using the version 2.0.1 of Dagger.

Anyone know why sometimes is null and sometimes not? It's a bug?

**EDIT 1:**

If you noticed, I have a list in this fragment, when the user trigger the pull to refresh, I call a method inside the my activity, like:

```
((BaseActivity)getContext).update();
```

This method call a async task and at the end of it, I use the adapter from the ViewPager (I use the OgacleJapan - SmartTabLayout) to get the current fragment that is visible, look like:

```
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    if(fragment != null) {
      if(fragment instanceof MyFragment) {
        ((MyFragment) fragment).doSomething();
      }
      if(fragment instanceof MyFragment2) {
        ((MyFragment2) fragment).doSomething();
      }
    }
```

I think this cast can be the problem. I added a recursivity to verify the consistency of the variables inside the view and I noticed that never returns null, if I call these variables inside of the fragment. If I call from activity, returns null.

Comment: Your module doesn't actually ever provide an instance of the presenter. I don't see why this is supposed to work. Also, your presenter instance dies along with your activity on rotation, so I hope you are managing that with `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: In this case, onCreate() will be called again, not?
But I don\`t rotate the screen, I don\`t do anything with the lifecycle.

Comment: Ah... As per your link at https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/Dagger2Scopes/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/github/jorgecastilloprz/dagger2scopes/android/di/GameDetailsModule.java you specify the @Inject on the constructor, and that allows you to receive it as a parameter. Interesting, I didn't know dagger2 could do that. But I think binding implementation classes in the parameter is counterproductive. Anyways, deleted my answer until iII figure out what is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace adapter.getItem() to adapter.getPage(). This will solve the problem.